# Why can't I start OpenVPN outside the directory?

Tags: networking, linux, vpn

I am trying to set up Pi running 5.10.60+ to be a VPN portal.

When I start openvpn from within /etc/openvpn, I see this

```
pi@safeSpace:/etc/openvpn $ sudo openvpn us-free-01.protonvpn.net.udp.ovpn
Sun Jun 12 22:44:20 2022 WARNING: file './vpnlogin' is group or others accessible
Sun Jun 12 22:44:20 2022 OpenVPN 2.4.0 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr 29 2022
. . .
Sun Jun 12 22:45:45 2022 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

When I try to start outside /etc/vpn, I see this

```
pi@safeSpace:~ $ sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/us-free-01.protonvpn.net.udp.ovpn
 directory (errno=2)
Options error: --auth-user-pass fails with './vpnlogin': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.
```

When I move files into a directory under my home I get this when I am in that directory

```
pi@safeSpace:~/OpenVPN $ sudo openvpn us-free-01.protonvpn.net.udp.ovpn
. . .  
Sun Jun 12 22:51:11 2022 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

And when I am outside

```
pi@safeSpace:~ $ sudo openvpn ./OpenVPN/us-free-01.protonvpn.net.udp.ovpn
sudo: unable to resolve host safeSpace
Sun Jun 12 22:52:50 2022 WARNING: cannot stat file './vpnlogin': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Options error: --auth-user-pass fails with './vpnlogin': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.
```

The permissions are as follows

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 5906 Jun 12 22:31 us-free-01.protonvpn.net.udp.ovpn
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   50 Jun 12 22:30 vpnlogin
```

Comment: Ensure you have the full path to the `vpnlogin` file in the `auth-user-pass` directive in your configuration file. Eg: `auth-user-pass /Users/steve/openvpn/vpnlogin`. Note that there are more secure authentication methods that should be being used as opposed to stored credentials, but I digress.

Comment: @stevieb 
Here is what the config file looks like now: 

`auth-user-pass /etc/vpn/vpnlogin`

And the result 
`Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: us-free-04.prototype.net.udp.ovpn`

Determined that was self-inflicted and corrected the config 

Works now in /etc/openvpn! 

But outside /etc/openvpn, still getting the original error  
`Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/us-free-04.protonvpn.udp.ovpn`